# Improper values of Sin function

Tags: fortran

```
double precision, PARAMETER :: pi = 3.14159265358979323846
integer, parameter :: N =100
double precision :: h
h = 1.0/N

do i = 0, N-1
    u(0, i) = sin(pi*i*h)
end do
```

It does not give correct values of sin. Is something wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think you are getting incorrect values? What do you expect, and what do you get instead? Note that the value you give for PI has too many digits in it to be stored precisely in a double precision variable on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: you are assigning a single precision value into your ´pi´ constant. You should specify a kind specifier into the literal, like `3.14159265358979323846d0`. Actually, there are much better ways to work with real-type precision, like specifying a kind parameter to the real type, selecting the kind according to a specific precision (`selected_real_kind`), or a storage size (`iso_fortran_env` constants, like `real64`).

Comment: What is your declaration of `u`? You seem to be using `u` as if its indices start at 0, which is not the default for Fortran. If you have declared `double precision :: u(5, N)` then the first value of `u` would be at `(1, 1)`, not `(0, 0)`

Comment: REAL*8, dimension(0:500,-5:N+5) :: u. This is how "u" is declared

Comment: Well, it works for me. What are the wrong values you get? What happens when you just `print*, sin(pi/2)`?

Comment: I agree it is almost surely a duplicate. @BlackHeart You really have to report your incorrect values in the question. It is really necesaryf or potential reopenning. Also, all declarations must be present.

Comment: Also, you should change `1.0/N` to someting like `1.d0/N` or `dble(1)/dble(N)` to force double precision for `h`. Here, the variable `h` in in double precision but the computation `1.0/N` is not.